# Por que o Stack Overflow em Português não está listado no "footer" do Stack Exchange?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-intencional, design

Será que somos tão pequenos assim para não merecermos um espaço no footer? (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/#footer-menu)

Se somos equivalentes ao Stack Overflow ao ponto de levar o nome, acho que deveríamos, ao menos, estar sob ele.

Comment: Could be porque a maioria dos network users do not understand patavinas of português. Ou porque esqueceram mesmo :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Oops. Acabei de clicar em more e vi que estamos lá ><'. Tchau, pergunta.

Comment: Você ainda pode protestar porque fomos relegados ao "more" :)

Comment: Também acho, proteste :)

Comment: Acredito que o SOPT só seja interessante para quem mora no Brasil e Portugal (e demais países que dominam o português), caso contrário não acredito não haver relevância para o conteúdo geral do site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem mais de 100 comunidades (atualmente 133) no [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/):

> - Each of our 133 communities is built by people passionate about a focused topic.
> - Cada um das nossas 133 comunidades é feita por pessoas apaixonadas sobre um tema focado.

Seria inviável adiciona-las todas ao rodapé, provavelmente eles adicionam a mais populares.

Leve em consideração que se eles colocassem o *SOpt*, teriam que por o *[SOja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)*  e outras comunidades como o da *[língua alemã](https://german.stackexchange.com/)* também teria que aparecer.

> Sim, existe o *[Stack Overflow em Japonês](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)* e acho que logo terá em *[alemão](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german)*.

O Stack Exchange não é um grupo de comunidades voltadas a tecnologia (mesmo tendo sido o Stack Overflow que alavancou esse estilo de comunidade), mas sim de variados assuntos, tem até uma proposta de uma comunidade de *[Café](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61013/coffee)* na *[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)*.

Hoje existem os mais variados assuntos, portanto o foco deles não é destacar os "Stack Overflows", mas provavelmente é destacar a **ferramenta** usada nas comunidades, atingindo vários tipos de grupos.

Veja pelo [tráfego](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) que existem muitos tipos de comunidades.

Porém nada disto impede você de abrir uma questão no [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) e sugerir destacar a comunidade SOpt :)

Comment: E se colocassem, logo abaixo: "Stack Overflow in other languages"?

Comment: @LucasHenrique StackOverflow no começo das comunidades sim era o mais "forte", mas agora não existe só comunidade de "programação", existem vários outros tipos de comunidades, logo terá uma comunidade sobre "Café" (Coffee)

Comment: SOja é brincadeira, né? Soja!!! <pergunta retórica pra galera do Sushi> . . . . O que me dá a idéia de [SOchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sochi) pro site em Russo

Comment: @brasofilo Eu e minhas abreviações abomináveis :(

Comment: Acabo de pensar, na hora em que Español e Russo se graduarem, uma feature-request no Metão podia ser interessante: *"International links on SE footer"*. Só Brasil e Rússia já são 2/5 dos [BRICS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRICS).